# Retrieve records which have age less than n months

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `products` with two columns: `id` as `INT` and `creation_date` as `DATE`.
I want to retrieve all products which have age less than 5 months. 
Which SQL query on mySQL could achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MySQL's [DATESUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE creation_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH)
```

From the documentation:

> DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit), DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)
>
> These functions perform date arithmetic. The date argument specifies
>   the starting date or datetime value. expr is an expression specifying
>   the interval value to be added or subtracted from the starting date.
>   expr is a string; it may start with a “-” for negative intervals. unit
>   is a keyword indicating the units in which the expression should be
>   interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use date time add functions defined [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
select *
from products
where creation_date > DATE_ADD(NOW(),  INTERVAL -5 MONTH);
```